# Finding range of a function with derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

we have  a function such that $$f(x):[0,1] \mapsto R$$
,f(x) is twice differentiable and also $ f(0) =0=f(1) $
and also satisfies $$f''(x)-2f'(x) +f(x) \ge e^x $$where x belongs in [0,1] so what is range of f(x) in this interval.
By Rolle's we know that if function is derivable then in at least one point in $[0,1]$ its derivative will be zero and $0$ is either  maximum or minimum of the function. Hence 
$$f''(x)  +f(x) \ge 0$$ and also $$f''(x)  +f(x) \ge e$$
Now if we can know know sign of $f''(x)$ we can find concavity of function and finally get idea of its range , so how do we find its sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hint:***

Take $F(x) = f(x)e^{-x}$ then we have $F(0) = F(1) = 0$ and

$$F''(x) = (f''(x) - 2f'(x) + f(x))e^{-x} \geq 1$$

since $f''(x) - 2f'(x) + f(x) \geq e^x$

So $F(x)$ is convex and...